# Convert first element of each factor to NA in R

Tags: r, vector, dataframe, subset, na

I have a dataframe simplified as following:

```
Day Place   dendrometer max

1   1       1   4684

2   1       1   4831

1   1       2   2486

2   1       2   2596

1   2       1   6987

2   2       1   6824
```

I need  the first element of each dendrometer   as NA, so every time R calculates “max” for a new dendrometer (independently of the place), starts with NA,  like this:

```
Day Place   dendrometer max

1   1       1   NA

2   1       1   4831

1   1       2   NA

2   1       2   2596

1   2       1   NA

2   2       1   6824
```

Could you also let me know I could calculate MEAN of the max column for each dendrometer within each ring (sapply, aggregate?) instead of calculating mean for the entire max column?
NOTE: dendro 1 in place 1 is different to dendro 1 in place 2, I need different information for each of them

Comment: Why do you *need* the NA values? What are  `rings`

Comment: Basically nothing you wrote after "I need the first element of each dendrometer as NA" makes any sense to me whatsoever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  library(data.table)
  myDat <- data.table(myDat, key="Day")

  # using the `mult` argument, make the first instance of each Day  NA
  myDat[.(Day), dendrometer := NA, mult="first"]

  # add mean
  myDat[, mean := mean(dendrometer, na.rm=TRUE), by=Day]

  # add max
  myDat[, max := max(dendrometer, na.rm=TRUE), by=Day]
```

### Results:

```
  > myDat
     Day Place dendrometer     mean  max
  1:   1     1          NA 3304.333 4831
  2:   1     1        4831 3304.333 4831
  3:   1     2        2486 3304.333 4831
  4:   1     2        2596 3304.333 4831
  5:   2     1          NA 6824.000 6824
  6:   2     1        6824 6824.000 6824
```

#### Sample Data Used:

```
  read.table(text=
  "Day Place   dendrometer
     1       1   4684
     1       1   4831
     1       2   2486
     1       2   2596
     2       1   6987
     2       1   6824", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE) -> myDat
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you always have only two measurements of one dendrometer in one place? If so, then you could just set every other value as NA:

```
#x is your data.frame
x<-read.table("clipboard",header=TRUE)
x[seq(1,nrow(x),by=2),4]<-NA
```

and the max values are the non-NA values

```
x[seq(2,nrow(x),by=2),4]
```

If your data is more complicated, this should work:

```
dup<-duplicated(x[,2:3]) #find the non-unique cases
x[!dup,4]<-NA #set the first measurements as NA
tapply(x[dup,4],which(dup),max) #compute max from others.
```

Note that for computing the mean you do not need to set the first measurements as NA.

Comment: The data is far more complicated, but I saw your point, and a variation of your example could work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the mean values of `max` an be calculated with `tapply`.

```
dat <- transform(dat,
                 mean = tapply(max, c(0, cumsum(abs(diff(dendrometer)))), mean))

  Day Place dendrometer  max   mean
1   1     1           1 4684 4757.5
2   2     1           1 4831 2541.0
3   1     1           2 2486 6905.5
4   2     1           2 2596 4757.5
5   1     2           1 6987 2541.0
6   2     2           1 6824 6905.5
```

You can use the `diff` function to find differences between `dendrometer` and the `is.na<-` function to replace values in `max` with `NA`.

```
is.na(dat$max) <- c(TRUE, diff(dat$dendrometer) != 0)

  Day Place dendrometer  max   mean
1   1     1           1   NA 4757.5
2   2     1           1 4831 2541.0
3   1     1           2   NA 6905.5
4   2     1           2 2596 4757.5
5   1     2           1   NA 2541.0
6   2     2           1 6824 6905.5
```

Comment: I think this wouldn't work when I have more than two days reading for each dendrometer. This is a simplification of my dataset. The real dataset has thousand of days and hundreds of readings per day and dendrometer.

Comment: No no OK, I think you are right and this will help me solve my problem. Thanks!!